# Gravity forms unset fields dynamically

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, wordpress-hook

I'm successfully populating the Gravity form fields using "gform_pre_render " hook. now i need to remove few fields dynamically. I spend hours to looking into documentation and did google searches but no luck. Its really helpful if someone know how to unset fields in gravity form. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i find solution to unset fields

inside [gform_pre_render](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_pre_render/) hook we can unset fields like this

```html
if( $field->id == 7 ){
   unset ( $form['fields'][7] );
}
```